# What does more than chance mean?

Tags: statistical-significance, interpretation

I'm interested in what exactly sentences like this mean:

> In the former case, participants correctly chose the larger city in
>   55% of the pairs, in the latter in 54% of the pairs, both rates
>   significantly different from chance.

Is it basically just that its significantly different from 50%?

UPDATE:

Here's another one:

```
But now here's another one I've found: In a pretest, one brand had been rated as higher quality, and participants could identify the higher-quality product 59 percent of the time in a blind test (substantially higher than chance, which was 33 percent). I still don't get how is 33 determined?
```

How do they get 33?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is probably what was intended, given the phrases "of the pairs".

Of course *statistically significant*, especially with a large enough sample, does not need to mean *substantial*.

**Added as a response to comments:**

The context seems to be [described here](http://www.sjdm.org/~baron/journal/11/rh00/rh00.pdf), including

> Imagine you are confronted with the names of two German cities, and
>   you recognize neither of them. There is no more information available
>   to infer which city is larger. What can you do?
>
> ...
>
> Drösemeyer (2000) and Hell used the names of smaller German cities,
>   between 45.000 and 60.000 and between 20.000 and 25.000 inhabitants.
>   This resulted in their German participants sometimes having heard of
>   neither of the two, and sometimes just recognizing the two by name,
>   but with no further information available from memory. In the former
>   case, participants correctly chose the larger city in 55% of the
>   pairs, in the latter in 54% of the pairs, both rates significantly
>   different from chance. Although these effects are tiny, they point to
>   an interesting exploitation of information from the mere names, even
>   if both cities are unrecognized.

That makes it clear that guessing one out of two is what was involved and suggests that there is on average a tiny positive amount of information about cities' sizes in their names.  But obviously it is not a particularly reliable way of estimating city size.

Comment: so they are comparing 54% to 50% ? how can that be meaningful at all?

Comment: We're assuming that "chance" means 50%.  In many cases that's not so--consider an experiment in which more than two choices are possible, for instance.  Generally, "chance" refers to the probabilities assigned by the null hypothesis.

Comment: @Daniel What is *not* meaningful about comparing 54% to 50%?  Perhaps you are asking whether the difference is scientifically *important.*  That's a different question than statistical significance.  Its answer depends on the context.  It might help to think of a "significant" difference as being a *detectable* one.

Comment: @whuber so for example in this case with 16 questions with 2 alternatives. How would you go about testing whether its significantly different from chance?

Comment: @Daniel In a standard way: adopt a probability model for "chance," select a test statistic, determine its distribution, and compare the actual statistic to that distribution.  One model views each answer as an independent random draw from a box with both alternatives (coded as 0 and 1) equally likely; a good statistic would be formed from the list of proportions of 1's, such as a negative log likelihood or (for largish samples) the sum of squares of their deviations from 1/2; large values of this statistic would be evidence of "significant differences from chance."

Comment: @Daniel It's worth noting that "significant" can be a rather subjective term. Levels chosen for significance can vary by discipline, and different tests may give contrary results.

Comment: @whuber I mean the more technical aspects. What does it mean technically to 'adopt a probability model for chance'?

Comment: @Daniel It means replacing aspects of the real world with idealized random processes.  In my preceding comment I treated the answers *as if* they had been obtained by drawing values out of a well-mixed box containing equal amounts of zeros and ones.  That's a probability model.  It describes a situation where respondents are independently guessing the answers to the questions.  A more complex model would be needed when it's likely answers will be correlated.  E.g., two questions might ask the same thing, so a *consistent* guesser would give identical answers.

Comment: @whuber so you basically mean giving answers to each question in a manner where 50% choose option1 and 50% choose option 2?

Comment: @Daniel Not quite: in this model, it will be unusual for the answers to split exactly 50:50.  This is a property of sampling with replacement.

Comment: @whuber okay but what I'm trying to figure out is how to specify such a model. for example I have 15 responses for 6 questions with two options each. and I would like to see whether people choose option a or b significantly more than chance. How do I go about specifying the chance model?

Comment: @Daniel Mathematically, you give a probability distribution.  Coding the answers as 0/1 identifies the sample space with $\{0,1\}^6$.  A sufficient statistic is the sum of these answers, a 6D vector $(x_i)$ with components in $\{0,1,\ldots,15\}$.  Assuming independence among people (which is clear) and among questions (debatable but reasonable in many cases), the null distribution is given by $6$ Binomial$(15,1/2)$ distributions, assigning a probability of $2^{-15\times 6}\prod_{i=1}^6\binom{15}{x_i}$ to $x$.

Comment: @whuber thanks now I understand. Can you recommend a book or paper where they discuss how to specify probability models based on different distributions?

Comment: @Daniel http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books+modeling

Comment: @whuber thanks for the useful links, however, I was hoping for something more basic to start with. for example specifying a simple chance distribution for the above problem, which shouldn't involve any complex considerations. just basically learning how to create sample distributions, etc

Comment: @Daniel I didn't want to offend you by suggesting basic stats texts, but that's where to begin.  Choose books by and for engineers if you want a lot of math; books by good statisticians if you want a good understanding with less math (I like Freedman, Pisani, & Purves, any edition); and books by social scientists if you want it all hidden from you :-).

Comment: @whuber thanks! i'll try to get the freedman book.

Comment: @Daniel Earlier editions are great and much cheaper than a new copy of the latest one.

Comment: @whuber thanks for the advice. But now here's another one I've found:  In a pretest, one brand had been rated as higher quality, and participants could identify the higher-quality product 59 percent of the time in a blind test (substantially higher than chance, which was 33 percent). I still don't get how is 33 determined?

Comment: @Daniel We're repeating ourselves: I answered that question in the very first comment here.